# can't load OID after add MIBS into net-snmp

Tags: net-snmp

I add Oracle MIBs into net-snmp by:

`mibs +OR-mib`  in snmp.conf

`#MIBS=+OR-mib` in shell

```
#export MIBS

#snmp restart
```

but when I reload by:
`#snmpwalk -v2c -c private 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.111`
I get:
`snmpv2-smi::enterprises.111= no such available on this agent at this OID`

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try re-starting snmpd daemon? I guess you missed this!

Comment: Before making a walk on the MIB, try to make a simple snmptranslate. This way you will be sure that MIB-path is exported.

Answer (score 1):

Loading a MIB on the local machine does not magically make data available. The agent needs to be extended to implement the MIB. This is covered in the Net-SNMP FAQ:

[I've installed a new MIB file.  Why can't I query it?](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/FAQ.html#I_ve_installed_a_new_MIB_file___Why_can_t_I_query_it_)

If you've installed an AgentX agent that implements the oracle MIBs, then it's likely an access control issue. See the FAQs on access control:

[How do I configure the agent?](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/FAQ.html#How_do_I_configure_the_agent_)